# How to pass QUERYPARAMETER to ViewModel constructor?

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

I'm Learning how to use on a maui app where I use AppShell to pass data from one view model to the next page viewmodel,and the using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm. but I dunno how to pass the return query parameter to next page viewmodel method.

viewmodel for Next Page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using TimesNewsApp.Models;
using TimesNewsApp.Services;

namespace TimesNewsApp.ViewModels
{
    [QueryProperty(nameof(SelectedGenre), nameof(SelectedGenre))]
    public partial class MovieListGenrePageViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Result> Movie { get;} = new();

        [ObservableProperty]
        private Genre selectedGenre;
        NewsApiManager apiService;

        public Command GetMovieComand { get; }

        public MovieListGenrePageViewModel(NewsApiManager apiService)
        {
            this.apiService = apiService;
            Task.Run(async () => await GetMovies(SelectedGenre));
        }


        async Task GetMovies(Genre SelectedGenre)
        {
            if (IsBusy)
                return;

            try
            {
                IsBusy = true;
                if (SelectedGenre == null)
                    return;
                
                Movie movies = await apiService.GetMovieByGenre(SelectedGenre.Id);
                if (Movie.Count != 0)
                    return;
                foreach (var item in movies.results)
                    Movie.Add(item);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to get movie: {ex.Message}");
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error!", ex.Message, "OK");
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I try to use this in the consructor;

```
public MovieListGenrePageViewModel(NewsApiManager apiService){
        ...
this.SelectedGenre = SelectedGenre;
Task.Run(async () => await GetMovies(SelectedGenre));
}
```

but SelectedGenre returns null. please how can I set Object SelectedGenre to the GetMovie method?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, since the constructor is called before the QueryParameter is passed to the ViewModel.

However, you have many ways to achieve what you are looking for.
One way is to set the Appearing method of the page and call a function of your ViewModel.

In your xaml page set

`Appearing="Page_Appearing"`

Then in your page .cs file set and make sure you have your ViewModel accessible. (e.g. define in XAML or use a locator/ container service)

```
    public AddProjectPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = ViewModel;
    }

    private async void Page_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnAppearing();


        await this.ViewModel.InitAsync(); //  

    }
```

In your ViewModel define a function called `InitAsync` to do all your initialisation stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you want pass the parameter to the next page, you can use the Shell. You can put the data in the dictionary and pass it to the next page.

```
  async void OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Animal animal = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as Animal;
        var navigationParameter = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "Bear", animal }
        };
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"nextpage", navigationParameter);
    }
```

In the next page, Navigation data can be received by decorating the receiving class with a `QueryPropertyAttribute` for each string-based query parameter and object-based navigation parameter.The first argument for the `QueryPropertyAttribute` specifies the name of the property that will receive the data, with the second argument specifying the parameter id.

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(Bear), "Bear")]
public partial class BearDetailPage : ContentPage
{
    Animal bear;
    public Animal Bear
    {
        get => bear;
        set
        {
            bear = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public BearDetailPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

For more details you can refer to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data